# ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Tags: android-studio

he estado tratando de correr el emulador de Android en mi maquina pero no lo he conseguido, al tratar de emular obtengo el siguiente error:

Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Mi equipo es una Laptop Lenovo Ideapad 310.

En la BIOS tengo habilitada la virtualización, pero en Windows features ahi no he encontrado Hyper -V para poderla activar ese podría ser el problema? o como la encuentro en mi equipo?
Les comparto las imágenes de mi sistema y todo lo que tengo activado para emular el dispositivo en mi equipo, esperando puedan ayudarme a solucionar el problema.

[image: Sistema y requerimientos]

[image: Obtención del error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veras los procesadores AMD tienen muchísimos problemas con el tema de las maquinas virtuales con Google.

(Tu tienes un AMD)

Deberías crear un dispositivo en el que el sistema sea compatible con tu CPU, exactamente debe ser una versión arm (etc...)

[image: Ejemplos de las versiones que debes instalar]

Pero no te vale la pena porque son muy lentas, te recomiendo que instales GenyMotion

[Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)

Funcionan muy bien y tienen una versión gratuita. (Funciona con VirtualBox)

Te paso un enlace de un video tutorial de youtube que lo explica muy bien y de manera sencilla

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kOD855oC2LQ)

Saludos y mucha suerte